# C++ name lookup inconsistency for template/overloaded functions

Tags: c++, overload-resolution, name-lookup

I'm building a minimal binary parser/serializer for one of my projects and I got this error that seems inconsistent at first. I have two top functions I want to expose `T parse<T>(bytes)` and `bytevec serialize<T>(T const&)` and from these two templated functions I delegate the serialization to overloaded functions based on the specific type provided. The problem is that the parsing side works fine, but the serialization side doesn't compile because it cannot see the overloaded function if it is defined after the top `serialize` function.

```
using bytevec = std::vector<uint8_t>;
using bytes = std::span<const uint8_t>;

template <typename T>
bytevec serialize(T const& data) {
    bytevec b{};
    serialize(data, b); // error: no matching function for call to 'serialize(const int&, bytevec&)
    return b;
}

void serialize(int data, bytevec& b) {
    b.push_back(0xff);
    b.push_back(0xaa);
}

template <typename T>
struct tag {};

template <typename T>
T parse(bytes b) {
    return parse(b, tag<T>{}); // fine
}

int parse(bytes b, tag<int>) { return b[1]; }

void test() {
    static std::array<uint8_t, 2> data{0xff, 0xaa};
    auto res1 = parse<int>(std::span(data));
    auto res2 = serialize(res1);
}
```

[Link to compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/G1KsGY78T)

Why is it ok for the top `parse` function to call an overloaded function defined later (`int parse(bytes, tag<int>)` and for the `serialize` function the overloaded function needs to be defined before in order to compile?

Thank you

Comment: Questions should really be self-contained. Please post the code _here_ as a [mre], with enough information so that no one has to follow a link.

Comment: It sounds like you’re asking about pre declarations. C++ is not a multi pass compiler type of language. All functions must be declared before usage.

Answer (score 0):

[ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) doesn't work for built-in types such as `int`.

- For

  ```
  template <typename T>
  bytevec serialize(T const& data) {
      std::vector<uint8_t> b{};
      serialize(data, b);
      return b;
  }
  ```

  With `T=int`

  `serialize(data, b);` uses previous declaration, and can be looked-up in same namespace than `std::vector<uint8_t>` (so `std`). But no previous declarations and no `std::serialize`.
- For

  ```
  template <typename T>
  T parse(bytes b) {
      return parse(b, tag<T>{});
  }
  ```

  with `T=int`

  `parse(b, tag<int>{})` uses previous declaration, and can be looked-up in same namespace than `tag<int>` (so the global one) and `std::span<const uint8_t>` (so `std`). No previous declaration nor `std::parse`, but `::parse(int, tag<int>{})` exist.

Comment: I tried using fully qualified function name `::serialize` but that also doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I found the answer, unqualified name lookup inside function templates uses the template definition context by default and only for ADL it uses both template definition and template instantiation context.